# Problema al montar mi NAS en mi pc linux con el comando mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor

Por por ahora estoy probando sin DNS para conectarme de forma local.Mi Linux es Ubuntu 18.x. Estoy intentandolo con el siguiente comando:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o user=hola,pass=adios //ip/ /home/miUser/Documentos/NAS/.`

Y me esta arrojando el siguiente error:

> mount error(2): No such file or directory Refer to the mount.cifs(8)
>   manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Debo decir que el directorio en mi pc existe (/home/miUser/Documentos/NAS/). 
Me gustaria indicar que no se que **sistema de archivos usar** = cifs,etc....
La ip local es correcta tambien.

Comment: Si existe `home/miUser/NAS/` porque le estas pasando `/home/miUser/Documentos/NAS/`????

Comment: disculpa, me equivoque al ponerlo aqui. Pero no es eso. Gracias.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para que la corrijas.

Comment: Porque tu directorio de la unidad tiene un punto al final? /home/miUser/Documentos/NAS/.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con esto

```
mount.cifs //ip.del.nas.elegido/directorioamontar /home/usuario/carpetadondesemontara/ -o user=usuario,password=nuestracontraseña
```

Pero esto solo lo agregara en la sesion, si quieres acceder desde que encienda, agrégalo a un cron

Comment: Que va, me dice lo mismo : mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: Intenta agregar la version de samba, puede que sea eso, vers=2.0

mount.cifs //ip.del.nas.elegido/directorioamontar /home/usuario/carpetadondesemontara/ -o user=usuario,password=nuestracontraseña,vers=2.0

Comment: si puedes revisar la version y asi no erras 

mount -t cifs -o user=myuser,vers=1.0 //myserver/myshare /home/user/myserver/myshare/

Comment: Sigue sin ir. Las credenciales y los directiorios existen.

Comment: Más que a un cron sería conveniente añadir la correspondiente línea en el fichero /etc/fstab

Comment: Si los directorios existen, podría ser problema por samba

Intenta montandolo 

smbclient -L \\ip

verifica si no te da algun problema, si todo sale correctamente entonces intentas nuevamente montarlo.